# Find out how a mystery UIView is being added to my view hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm having a h3ll of a time with AutoLayout.
I've been using Reveal to look at various views of the app and see if anything is 'revealing' there.  Anyway, I have this weird view ***circled in red*** that's not in my nib, yet is somehow being added to my view hierarchy.  I don't find any code that's adding it either, so I'm somewhat mystified how it's getting there.

If you were going to investigate how this view is making its way into your heirarchy, what would you do?

[image: MysteryView]

It looks like something is happening between -viewDidLoad completing, and -viewDidAppear, because this recursive description call I made at those points shows a view that gets resized to a ridiculous dimension (highlighted in yellow, look at the size change)

I also did a constraint debug call that listed all the constraints and their ambiguity status.
I still can't figure out where the circled view is coming from though, or why it's being resized as it is.

Note also that even though the recursive constraint debug call says there's ambiguous layout, there is no indication of that in Interface Builder where I set up the constraints, so I suspect this extra view is sneaking in somehow during execution and screwing everything up.

[image]

Comment: are you using some third party code named AGSMapView? The red circle might belong to it

Comment: Yes, I am.  I added additional info with another picture that shows several "recursive hierarchy" runs during execution, and to me it looks like a view that is containing the AGSMapView thats the problem ,but I can't find it in interface builder or code, hence the hair pulling mystery.